# How to train SVM in Open CV for android?

Tags: android, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

I am new to open CV and machine learning. I have a doubt regarding training the SVM for facial expression. I have downloaded the Cohn-Kanade facial expression database. Now do I need to extract the facial features from each image in the database and supply only the feature points as the SVM training data or do I need to supply the entire image as the training data ?

Answer (score 0):

For an SVM, supply only the feature points, especially if you can represent them as displacements from rest state.  You want a nice, tractable vector (15-20 points?) rather than a 2D array (128x128?) of pixels.  The full image might work if you were training a CNN (convolutional neural network), but that would take a while.